# How to represent a linear functional over $\mathbb{C}$ as a sum of linear functionals over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose, $l:X \to \mathbb{C}$ is a linear functional of a linear space $X$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$. Split it into a real part and an imaginary part:$$l(x) = l_1(x)+il_2(x), \text{for any} x \in X$$ $l_1$ and $l_2$ are linear functionals over $\mathbb{R}$.

It's been mentioned that $l_1$ and $l_2$ are related by $l_1(ix) = -l_2(x)$. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $L=L_1+iL_2$ is linear over $\mathbb{C}$ then we have
$$
L(ix) = L_1(ix) + iL_2(ix) 
$$
and
$$
L(ix) = iL(x) = i(L_1(x) + iL_2(x)) = -L_2(x) + iL_1(x).
$$

These two expressions are equal, so their real parts are equal. Thus
$$
L_1(ix)=-L_2(x).
$$
Equating their imaginary parts is valid, but gives you the same result and so no new information. In particular, this shows that a linear function over $\mathbb{C}$ is completely determined by its real part (or by its imaginary part).